# validate if the aplication is open/active in cordova app andorid

Tags: php, android, cordova, firebase

I have an app in Android developed with cordova, and I have the firebase plugin running.

When I send a notification to the device I want than that notification open the app in a specific location, I just do it, but when the app is open and I send any notification, the app just jumps to the location specified.

I want to know if exist some function or else who show you if the app is open, then do not execute nothing.

I am using cordova and javascript.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the **pause** and **resume** events you can find out whether the app is in foreground or background.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function readyCallback() {


    var isAppInForeground = true;


    document.addEventListener("pause", function pauseCallback() {
      isAppInForeground = false;
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("resume", function resumeCallback() {
      isAppInForeground = true;
    }, false);

});
```

Now, when you recieve the notification check the flag **isAppInForeground** as following

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
    console.log(notification);
    if(isAppInForeground){
        // avoid the navigation
    }
    else{
       // allow the navigation
    }
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is the solution for my issue!